# Need Help on Customized Reporting

Tags: citrus-framework

I have integrated One Third Party Reporting API with Citrus, Have implemented the TestListener interface. I am observing One Test Case is Printed Twice in the Reporting Dash Board, The Moment i debug i see the Reporting method is executed twice.

```
@Override
public void onTestSuccess(TestCase test) {

    ETest.log(LogStatus.PASS, "Test Case Passed"); (--> This line Executed twice every time 

}
```

Can you guys help me here.

regards
BJ

Comment: Need more details on your configuration setup. Please also describe how you have added the custom reporting class to the Spring framework application context configuration. This could lead us to the solution when the reporter is added twice somehow

Comment: I have added the Bin class to Application Context(  <bean class="com.consol.citrus.integration.Demo.ExtntReportImp"/>) The below code i am Executing as Test Case          http()
             .client(todoClient1)
             .receive()
             .response(HttpStatus.OK)
             .validate("$.statusCode", "200");  Below is My Implementation Code --> public void onTestSuccess(TestCase test) {
 ETest.log(LogStatus.PASS, "Test Case Pass");
  
 }

Comment: Have Observed onTestSuccess is Executed Twice every Time  for PASS condition

Comment: I tried with the Console Logging                               @Override
 public void onTestSuccess(TestCase test) {
  
        log.info("Test Case Pass");

  
 } In the Console the Message "Test Case Pass" is printed twice aswell

Comment: Infact i observed today, The TestListener is executing twice while running the Script, For this i am getting same report file printed twice

Comment: Investigated and can not reproduce that error. I also added a new sample for exactly that custom reporting. See https://github.com/christophd/citrus-samples/tree/master/sample-reporting

Please review the sample and let me know how it works for you.

Comment: Thanks much Chris for the Help, The issue is resolved

Comment: Could you please share what fixed the issue and what the initial problem was all about?

Comment: Hi Chris, The error is causing as i didn't close the report from my local test cases, added the below piece of script here.   @AfterMethod
   public void quit1()
   {
    if(extent!=null)
    {
     extent.endTest(test);
     extent.flush();  
    }    
   }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find out how to add custom reports in Citrus: http://citrusframework.org/samples/reporting/

Also see the [sample github sources](https://github.com/christophd/citrus-samples/tree/master/sample-reporting)